# Why doesnt my Python function print to console?

Tags: python

I can't seem to figure out why my function doesn't print anything when called.

This is the function (and a list that's used in the function):

```
old_letters = ['a', 'p', 'c', 'f']

def try_update_letter_guessed(letter_guessed, old_letters_guessed):
    length = len(letter_guessed)
    english_validation = letter_guessed.isalpha()
    already_used = letter_guessed in old_letters_guessed

    if (length > 1) or (english_validation == False) or (already_used == True):
        print("X")
        delim = "->"
        res = delim.join(sorted(old_letters_guessed))
        print(res)
        return False
    elif (length == 1) and (english_validation == True) and (already_used == False):
        old_letters_guessed.append(letter_guessed)
        return True
```

However, when I call my function (with arguments) like so:
`try_update_letter_guessed('A', old_letters)`
it doesn't print anything at all.
What am I missing?

Comment: You have 3 possible paths through your function, but only one has any print functions.  The first `if` b;pcl has some print functions, but the `elif` block doesn't and if neither block is executed and falls through, there are no print calls.  Put some print calls in both those blocks as "sanity checks" and you might see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `letter_guessed` is `'A'`, then `(length > 1) or (english_validation == False) or (already_used == True)` is not true, so this goes to the elif, and that doesn't print anything.

If you try with arguments which *will* make that condition true, then it does print:

```
>>> try_update_letter_guessed('AB', old_letters)
X
A->a->c->f->p
False
>>> try_update_letter_guessed('a', old_letters)
X
A->a->c->f->p
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `print()` inside the `elif` block. Because the argument `'A'` will only lead into the `elif` block so after appending to the `old_letters_guessed` if you want to see something in the console use the `print()` function.